# CheckStyle SuppressionFilter module file path for Eclipse and Maven compatibility

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, filepath, checkstyle

### Situation

I have a project with a CheckStyle setup which uses the `SuppressionFilter` to set the `checkstyle_suppressions.xml` file as ignore file.

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${config_loc}/checkstyle_suppressions.xml"/>
    <property name="optional" value="false"/>
</module>
```

The `checkstyle.xml` file containing this `SuppressionFilter` is referenced to from the projects `pom.xml` file:

```
<!-- Checkstyle plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>checkstyle</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectories>${project.compileSourceRoots}</sourceDirectories>
                        <testSourceDirectories>${project.testCompileSourceRoots}</testSourceDirectories>
                        <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                        <configLocation>${basedir}/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                    <version>8.9</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

### Problem

When performing a CheckStyle check using Java Eclipse, everything functions as expected. When building with maven, however, the build fails due to the `${config_loc}` property not being set. Original error:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check (checkstyle) on project MyProject: Failed during checkstyle execution: Failed during checkstyle configuration: unable to parse configuration stream: Property ${config_loc} has not been set -> [Help 1]`

When changing `${config_loc}/checkstyle_suppressions.xml` to `checkstyle_suppressions.xml` in the configuration above, maven builds the application as expected, but Java Eclipse's CheckStyle plugin is not able to parse the file anymore, printing the following exception to the log:

> !ENTRY net.sf.eclipsecs.core 4 0 2018-06-07 05:40:02.460
>   !MESSAGE Checkstyle-Plugin: cannot initialize module SuppressionFilter - Unable to find: checkstyle_suppressions.xml
>   !STACK 0
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module SuppressionFilter - Unable to find: checkstyle_suppressions.xml
>       at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:460)
>       at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:198)
>       at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckerFactory.createCheckerInternal(CheckerFactory.java:299)
>       at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckerFactory.createChecker(CheckerFactory.java:133)
>       at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.Auditor.runAudit(Auditor.java:141)
>       at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckstyleBuilder.handleBuildSelection(CheckstyleBuilder.java:306)
>       at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckstyleBuilder.build(CheckstyleBuilder.java:172)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:142)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:232)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
>   Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Unable to find: checkstyle_suppressions.xml
>       at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.utils.CommonUtils.getUriByFilename(CommonUtils.java:510)
>       at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.filters.SuppressionsLoader.loadSuppressions(SuppressionsLoader.java:202)
>       at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.filters.SuppressionFilter.finishLocalSetup(SuppressionFilter.java:100)
>       at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:194)
>       at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:455)
>       ... 18 more

### Solve attempts

I have tried to set this `${config_loc}` variable in the maven pom in multiple places, but without success.

### Question

How can I set up my CheckStyle configuration so that it works for both Maven and Java Eclipse? I am looking for a distributable solution, meaning that other developers which clone or fork this project will not face this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem by adding `<propertyExpansion>config_loc=${basedir}</propertyExpansion>` to the projects `pom.xml` file. For anyone who has a similar issue, the CheckStyle maven plugin setup is now:

```
<!-- Checkstyle plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>checkstyle</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectories>${project.compileSourceRoots}</sourceDirectories>
                        <testSourceDirectories>${project.testCompileSourceRoots}</testSourceDirectories>
                        <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                        <configLocation>${basedir}/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                        <propertyExpansion>config_loc=${basedir}</propertyExpansion>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                    <version>8.9</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```